# Set printer preferences

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printing, printer, powershell

I am writing a script setting up printers and drivers. One of the driver I install, contains a bug for old printers used with platforms further than Windows Vista.

I need to update the preferences of that printer and uncheck the `Excel Job Control` option. Unfortunately, I have found no way to get/set the printer's preferences. I cannot use the `Set-Printer.exe` or similar tools for I am still using PowerShell 2.0 (Windows 7).

Any alternative I can use? This process could follow a different path: using the `printui.exe` (`PrintUI DLL`) I can display the preferences of a printer. Is there any way in PS to interact with the UI? E.g. selecting tabs and un/checking options.

Answer (score 0):

[rundll32 printui documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rundll32-printui)

example to set certain settings:

```
RUNDLL32.EXE PRINTUI.DLL, PrintUIEntry /Sr /n "exampleName" /a "C:\ExampleFolder\Example.dat" u
```